# compile errors with junit

Tags: java, junit, java-6

I am trying to get some code form a course to work on my current installation: eclipse 3.4.2, a project with jdk1.60_13, JUnit 4_4.3.1 but the JUnit types `Theories` and `@DataPoint` cannot be resolved. Also e.g. the `replay()` and `verify()` methods are not recognized. What am I doing wrong (apart from using Java)?

Answer (score 0):

ok, I mistook JUnit 4_4.3.1 for 4.4 but of course it means version 4: specific version: 4.3...